# angularJS + jQuery jeditable plugin work together

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I am trying to write a directive for the jeditable plugin so when it changes the value, it will change also edit the model of the edited element.

So i wrote something like that, [**JS Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/CThYh/9)
but i don`t know how to get the object that bound to the object in the list.

**JS:**

```
var app = angular.module("app", []);

app.controller('ctrl', function ($scope) {
    $scope.lst = [{
        id: 1,
        name: "item1"
    }, {
        id: 1,
        name: "item1"
    }, {
        id: 2,
        name: "item2"
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: "item3"
    }, {
        id: 3,
        name: "item3"
    }];
});

app.directive('uiEditable', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            element.editable("/echo/json/", {
                onblur: 'submit',
                onsubmit: function (response, settings) {
                    //here i need to update the model
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Comment: thank you, looked for how to style the code...

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Pass your item in in an isolated scope:

```
app.directive('uiEditable', function(){
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            item: '='
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs){
            element.editable("/echo/json/", {
                onblur: 'submit',
                onsubmit: function(response, settings){
                    alert(scope.item);
                }
            });
        }
    };
});
```

'scope.item' will now give you a reference to the item inside your directive.

Comment: i did tried that but now, the the list is not generates properly,
look at that, http://jsfiddle.net/HrKVk/

Comment: Oops I forgot the jsfiddle. I don't have it to hand, but you need to add the attribute item='item' to your repeating element. Edit http://jsfiddle.net/HrKVk/2/

Answer (score 3):

This uses ngModel to update back to the model. (so don't forget ng-model on element)

```
app.directive('uiEditable', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function (scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            if (!ngModel) return; // do nothing if no ng-model

            element.editable(function (val) {
                var tVal = $.trim(val);
                if (ngModel.$viewValue !== tVal)
                     scope.$apply(function () { return ngModel.$setViewValue(tVal); });
                return tVal;
            });
        }
    };
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using the jeditable plugin?  This plugin seems to only duplicate in jQuery what you could already do in angular using ng-model alone and no plugin required.

If you just want to create text which can be edited in place like jEditable does, instead of creating a custom directive simply using ng-submit, ng-click, ng-hide and ng-model.  Here's a rough example.

The view:

```
<form ng-submit="submit()">
  <div ng-hide="showEdit"
       ng-click="showEdit = true">
       {{foo.bar}}
  </div>
  <div>
    <input  type="text"
            ng-show="showEdit"
            ng-model="foo.bar" />
  </div>
  <a href="#" ng-show="showEdit" 
              ng-click="submit();">done</a>
</form>
```

And the controller:

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope) {

  $scope.foo = {
    bar: 'some text'
  };

  $scope.showEdit = false;

  $scope.submit = function() {
    // hide the edit field
    $scope.showEdit = false;
    // submit form
    console.log('submit form');
  }

});
```

Comment: the plugin gives me much more, like sending the data to the server...
just for learning, my problem is more conceptual, i wanna get referance to the item.name, so after some manipulation i will can update it, and i dont know how to to that

Comment: Sending data to the server is something you should be doing in angular too.  Simple fact is that you shouldn't really be trying to edit the dom directly with jQuery in an angular app if you can help it.